# Clear markers from Google Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have added map on fragment activity and added several marker using addMarker function, but i am able to remove all markers , I am getting notification for different list of markers,

Now i wants to remove all markers and add new one.

one way to keep all markers in list and remove one by one, (marker.remove())

Is there any better way to clear all marker.

Comment: there is clear() method

Answer (score 213, accepted):

If you want to clear "all markers, overlays, and polylines from the map", [use `clear()` on your `GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#clear%28%29).

Comment: Should I call remove() on all of them before doing that? I mean, if I still have an ArrayList with those Markers, I suppose I'm still having an active reference to those Markers, so they will remain on memory even if I clear the map.

Am I right about this or clearing the map wipes the references to the Markers?

Comment: @santirivera92: "Should I call remove() on all of them before doing that?" -- AFAIK, you should not need to. "if I still have an ArrayList with those Markers, I suppose I'm still having an active reference to those Markers, so they will remain on memory even if I clear the map" -- yes, but that is *your* code, not Google's. If *you* hold onto `Marker` objects separately from the map, *you* need to let go of those. `clear()` will remove them *visually*.

Comment: Of course. So, clearing my ArrayLists and then clearing the map will get rid of them forever?

Comment: @santirivera92: Yes, it should. Nothing else should be holding on to them.

Comment: Also note that `clear()` function won't reset the `Marker` IDs. Basically you won't get `m0` again for new `Marker` adding.

Comment: @Prasad Is there any way to get m0 again?

Comment: However `clean` will also remove the toolbar (direction etc.) from the map. That's why the method is named `clean`.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not wish to clear polylines and only the markers need to be removed follow the steps below.

First create a new Marker Array like below

```
List<Marker> AllMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

Then when you add the marker on the google maps also add them to the Marker Array (its AllMarkers in this example)

```
for(int i=0;i<places.length();i++){

                LatLng location = new LatLng(Lat,Long);
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(location);
                markerOptions.title("Your title");

                 Marker mLocationMarker = Map.addMarker(markerOptions); // add the marker to Map
                    AllMarkers.add(mLocationMarker); // add the marker to array

                }
```

then finally call the below method to remove all markers at once

```
 private void removeAllMarkers() {
        for (Marker mLocationMarker: AllMarkers) {
            mLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        AllMarkers.clear();

    }
```

call from anywhere to remove all markers

```
removeAllMarkers();
```

I found this solution when i was looking for a way to remove only the map markers without clearing the polylines. Hope this will help you too.