# How to reset marker IDs after call GoogleMap.clear() v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Based on this post ([Clear markers from Google Map in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663793/clear-markers-from-google-map-in-android)) and in the `@Prasad` comment "*Also note that clear() function won't reset the Marker IDs. Basically you won't get m0 again for new Marker adding*."

I have a list of marker saved and i also have implemented a `onMarkerClickListener(`) which shows certain information abut it. The only way that i know i have to "know" and associate the marker with my list of my_objects are the marker_id....but, the problem is when I call `GoogleMap.clear()` function to reset all the info, (I clear both the Map and the list of markers saved), so when i add new marker the IDs doesn't begin by m0...

My question is, is there a way to reset the markers ID? or do i have a better way to do this `marker <-> my_object` association?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought.  Instead of trying to clear the IDs, is it possible to try remember the last added ID number.  Then use this number on your next add marker function ?  Just a quick thought to an alternative solution, hop it helps

Comment: yes i can but then what? how i know which marker was selected???

Comment: well, i finally use the marker.position to know which object "was associated", by computing distance between merker.position and my_object.position....i didn't find another better way since Marker hasn't a setTag() for instance.